# Preposition following "boarded"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which one is the correct preposition -

```
She boarded ____ his compartment.
```

I am confused between in and at. And on second thought, will it be okay if I skip the preposition here?

The situation is that a girl boarded the train and the compartment happened to be the same as the compartment a boy named Max was in. I've tried various attempts but could not find a way which was not verbose.

Comment: One boads a boat or train, but not a compartment. No preposition is necessary, but your sentence as written is still incorrect.

Comment: I agree with @James that the verb _board_ seems off. Change the verb, and the preposition might be _into_: "She shuffled into the compartment where Max was seated." As an aside, this might be a better question for [ell.se] – more info on that available [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3722).

Comment: If by compartment you really mean "carriage" then it would be ok to use "She boarded his carriage" to mean she boarded the train in the same carriage as the boy...

Comment: @MarvMills yes it came to me but i discarded it cause I felt - "his carriage" sounded like that he owned the carriage

Comment: "She *found herself* in his compartment" would be another possibility.

Comment: @J.R. But none of the suggestions here, including your own, gets the OP's message across, as they want to tell it. My assumption is that it was one of the old-fashioned compartment carriages, like we used to have in Britain. Each compartment had two bench seats facing each other and held six people. If my memory serves me right, you could actually board the train straight into a compartment, or at least some of them. The OP wants to say *She boarded at his compartment*, and that is perfectly correct English.

Comment: @WS2 Ah, nostalgia, I know the sort of compartment you mean! But "*She boarded at his compartment*" sounds awfully odd to me. "*She boarded at Crewe*", by all means.

Comment: @LachlanDominic Indeed 'she boarded at Crewe, at the very compartment were her future husband was seated'. It sounds like a girl meets boy story to me.

Comment: @WS2 It's still the preposition *at* with *compartment* that bugs me! It's definitely an (old-fashioned) romance, as you say. I'd prefer something like, "*She boarded the train, [and] straight into his compartment*". The word *straight* might even reinforce the idea of blundering into each other's arms. Cue for violins.

Comment: @LachlanDominic Let's construct some more dialogue. It has now gone from being a romance to being a murder trial. *Counsel for the prosecution* Where exactly did you board the train? Did you board through a door into a corridor or one into a compartment? *Witness* Into a compartment. *Counsel* Was it the one where the accused was sitting? *Witness* Yes I boarded AT/INTO/ that compartment. OK it works better with *into* there. But I fancy that is because the listener has already learned that she boarded the train. Coming cold to that information I think you need *at*.

Comment: This was the type of carriage: https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQPs2dqehNl4_YtHCNoJuVUlRWqXzy_BpQVZbWcgtZ4sYE_ZdGG

Comment: @MarvMills But, Mr Mills, please tell the court where, on 12th October last, you boarded the train? I know it was at Crewe. But where on the train did you board?

Comment: @WS2 I think *at* is the best preposition when specifying *how far along the train* you boarded it. We say *at the head/centre of the train*. So if you're using Max's compartment as the reference point, that's fine. But here the compartment remains a reference point in relation to the *exterior* of the train as seen from the platform, and since it conveys no notion of *ingress*, essential to our story, I fear that the reader might find it unsatisfactory, or even confusing. I'm going to have to stop here for today, sorry, but hope very much to converse on a future occasion :)

Comment: @WS2 - If your memory serves you right (and I have no reason to think it doesn't), and one can "actually board the train straight into a compartment," could you not just say, _"She boarded his compartment"_ as well? Not sure a preposition is required.

Comment: None. Please visit [ell.se] ODO -> http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/board Voting to close as GR.

Comment: @J.R.I have proved my memory is in working order. You will note I have posted a picture of the type of carriage in question. The problem I have with your suggestion is that one does not 'board a compartment'. One enters a compartment. So the 'boarding' relates to getting on the train. So it becomes a question of 'where, on the train, did she board; at the front, at the rear, or where?'. Answer; 'at his compartment'.

Answer (score 2):

"She boarded the train, [entering] at his compartment."

Answer (score -1):

She boarded into his compartment/ She boarded into her compartment

Comment: You've used the same preposition "into" in both examples. How does that answer the question or help? The possessive pronouns i.e. *his* and *her* are not in discussion. To improve the quality of your answer, could you refer to some sources, or give a brief explanation?

Answer (score -1):

Having given this a lot (too much!) thought, I think the best way of stating this is:

"She boarded the train in his compartment".

That does not include a clumsy use of "board" and also specifies the co-location necessary for the context.